# sql break select if condition is false after multiply successfully results in a raw

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have an ordered dictionary in SQL database that looks like

```
word   meaning
word1  meaning1_word1
word1  meaning2_word1
word2  meaning1_word2
```

I want to select all word1 and then terminate the select statement

and it's should looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dictionary 
WHERE word = "word1" WHILE (word = "word1")
```

P.S. solution should work with SQLite or Postgres

Comment: Doesn't this do what you want?  `SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'word1'`

Comment: yes, it is, but db would search until the end and it is might be very expensive if program query many words. And, I prefer to optimize it.

Comment: the easiest would be declaring a cursor and fetching it with arbitrary length until the value changes, but it would be most probably not compatible solution for postgres AND sqllite

Comment: If there is an index on the column `word` then the database would not "search until the end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe worth ordering by the word and then adding onto the where clause to be below or equal to the word being looked up....

```
SELECT * 
FROM dictionary 
WHERE word = 'word1' 
  AND word <= 'word1' 
ORDER by word
```

Comment: `word = "word1"` is invalid in Postgres because there is no column `"word1"` - strings need to be put between single quotes

Comment: SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'word1'  AND word <='word1' ORDER by word

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be writing the query as:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM dictionary d.
WHERE d.word = 'word1';
```

If you want the first match, then add `limit 1` or `fetch first 1 row only`.

If you want performance, add an index on `dictionary(word)`:

```
create index idx_dictionary_word on dictionary(word);
```

This will speed the query -- assuming the constant and the word have the same (or compatible) collations.